# Can I perform a networking task when ScenePhase changes to .background?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I observe the `ScenePhase` in my View below to ensure the player is still playing the game:

```
struct ActiveGame: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
```

I do this so I can detect when the "host" leaves the app - as they won't be able to make network calls to keep the app running.

When `ScenePhase` changes to `.background` - I want to call a Cloud Function to remove them as host.

My question is, is app functionality limited when the `ScenePhase` is `.background`?

Will I still be able to call a Cloud Function?

Comment: You should have a few seconds of execution after your app goes to the background. Have you tried it to see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you observer for scene phase you can specify that you have long-running task, so system will give you more time to finish

```
@State private var taskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid

// ... other code
.onChange(of: scenePhase) { phase in
    switch phase {
        case .background:

        taskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { _ in
            // do this clean up due to time expired
        }
        guard taskIdentifier != .invalid else { return }

        // run your async task and in completion notify end background task
        run_some_API_task(completion: {
           if taskIdentifier != .invalid {
               UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskIdentifier)
               taskIdentifier = .invalid
           }
        }) 

        default:
            print(">> do something else")
    }
}
```

See here for more details https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/choosing_background_strategies_for_your_app